# Powering LCD Displays without a Breadboard

Tags: lcd, hardware, wires

I hope that this is not a silly question. I may be hoplelessly optimistic in asking, but is there any way to power & display information onto a LCD Display from an Arduino Uno.... Without the breadboard? I am working on a hardware project that has very strict space constraints, and the breadboard is simply not an option.

Comment: It will highly depend on the kind of LCD you consider connecting to your Arduino: some LCD displays can be directly wired to the UNO, others need extra components (typically for level shifting) that will need a breadboard, a stripboard or a PCB.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're looking at [this page](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LiquidCrystal) - the breadboard is merely a convenience, you can just hard-wire the LCD directly - most don't even come with that header plug soldered on.